# Spark Executors RAM and file Size

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am reading text files of size 8.2 GB(all files in a folder) with WholeTextFiles method.

The job that read the files got 3 executors each with 4 cores and 4GB memory a shown in picture..

Though the job page is showing 3 executors, only 2 executors are really working on the data.(i can understand that from stderr logs which would print the files it's reading). 3rd executor doesnt have any trace that it's processing files.

There are 2 partitions from the wholetextfile API..

2 executors had 4GB each total 8GB of memory. But my files had 8.2GB.

**Can anyone explain how the 2 executors with 8GB ram in total are having 8.2GB files?**

My job is sucesfully completed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the spark doc of the function WholeTextFiles:
 Each file is read as a single record and returned in a key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.

So a RDD record is an entire file content and the num partitions is equal to the number of files.
To have multiple partitions you can use the function textFile

Answer (score 0):

Each and every executor has memory overhead [ which is 10% of allocated memory or with a minimum of 384 M].

You can see the actual allocated memory from YARN Running Jobs.

Also, there is something called Container memory [min and max limit] allocation.