# How is spark task with extreme long line processed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I was using pyspark to process multiple log files, in which a record is split into multiple-line format, so I chose wholeTextFiles to read the data and then filter out what I want. Size of each file is ~800M and there are 4096 files in total. However, spark job crashed after processing some tasks, the following is my configuration and code.

configuration:

--num-executors 100
--executor-cores    1
--executor-memory   30G

core code:

```
file_rdd= sc.wholeTextFiles(inputDir, 2500)
print file_rdd.getNumPartitions()
out_rdd = file_rdd.flatMap(parseFileContent)\
                  .repartition(1000)\
                  .saveAsTextFile(title_outputDir)
```

It went crash after 300+ tasks were complete, running log showed as follows:

[image: crash log]
I also get the DAG Visualization here:

[image: job dag visualization]

it seems like repartition operation causes the crash, and stage 1 never starts.
BTW, here is more info about the tasks processed if it helps:

[image: tasks running and failure status 1]

[image: tasks running and failure status 2]

[image: tasks error log]

I find some related questions on so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288408/spark-executors-ram-and-file-size), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553492/spark-task-memory-allocation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824349/spark-execution-of-tb-file-in-memory), but they only explain high-level memory consumption rather than how the tasks are executed (with respect to each line in a file) and how many memory is needed for each line (when it is processed and after it is processed). Hope someone could help me out of this complicated notion, and any suggestions would be appreciated about how to process multi-line format file in pyspark (not scala, I know scala could use DataFrame to overcome this problem but I am not familiar with scala), thank you all!

Comment: Python code in PySpark runs outside the JVM and all the data has to be marshalled first, which could increase the amount of memory needed 3x-5x since Python uses 2-byte or 4-byte internal string representation. It will thus help if you could also provide the cluster configuration - # of nodes, cores and memory per node, etc.

Comment: Just a note: "I know scala could use DataFrame to overcome this problem but I am not familiar with scala" -> DataFrame API is also exposed within pyspark.

Comment: @HristoIliev I do not know the capacity of the cluster since I am not the administrator, however I am convinced that resources required by the above configuration, which are #executors=100, #cores=1 and executor-memory=30G, are accessible. So I guess #nodes=100, cores=1 and memory-per-node=30G

Comment: @EnzoBnl  it seems like being included in new version of pyspark, I will figure it out, thanks

Comment: I'm asking about the physical configuration. I doubt it has 100 nodes of one core each - single-core CPUs are very rare nowadays. My point is that if you give one core and 30 GB per executor you may end up with many executors on a single cluster node and run out of RAM. But since you are not getting SIGSEGV due to depleted virtual memory, that is not really the case.

Comment: Have you tried setting `spark.executor.pyspark.memory`? When submitting YARN jobs, this amount gets added to the memory requirement for each executor.

Comment: @HristoIliev thank you for your consideration, I do not think the problem comes from physical configuration however, like you said, there was no SIGSEGV sended. I think it might have something to do with the coalesce in stage 0 since it does not shuffle data like repartition operation does, but I have not tried it yet cause I already found a way to step away from the OOM problem with pyspark newAPIHadoopFile API, thanks to @EnzoBnl `s advice.

Answer (score 0):

`.repartition(1000)` will balance your spark partitions and is an expensive operation, `.coalesce(1000)` will just stack partitions on top of each other and not work too hard to balance them and is thus much less expensive operation.  Use `.coalesce()` to decrease the number of partitions from 4096 to 1000, and save `.repartition()` for when you need to increase the number of spark partitions. Try `.coaleesce(1000)`, you will end up with 1000 files in your output.